# Difference between pgAdmin and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Can someone tell me the difference between pgAdmin and postgreSQL? Are both of them one in the same? I can't draw a ER diagram in pgAdmin but was wondering if it's possible in postgreSQL?

Once I downloaded the postgreSQL it automatically downloaded the pgAdmin and the postgreSQL database is not in sight.

Comment: relationship rules can have subtleties not suited to manipulation using a graphical tool.  the database is a server it runs in the background. pg_admin is a client to connect to the server.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The PostgreSQL is a database engine implementing SQL standards. It usually listen as a server on a network tcp port to provide its abilities.

The pgAdmin is a sort of client. You are able to manipulate schema and data on an instance or multiple instances of PostgreSQL engines.

The MS Windows instalation package consists of both PostgreSQL server and PgAdmin client. So far right after the instalation you are able to manage your databases.

Answer (score 18):

> PostgreSQL (pronounced as post-gress-Q-L) is an open source relational
>   database management system ( DBMS ) developed by a worldwide team of
>   volunteers. PostgreSQL is not controlled by any corporation or other
>   private entity and the source code is available free of charge.
>
> The pgAdmin package is a free and open source graphical user interface
>   administration tool for PostgreSQL, which is supported on many
>   computer platforms.
>
> **phpPgAdmin** is a web-based administration tool for PostgreSQL written in PHP and based on the popular **phpMyAdmin** interface
>   originally written for MySQL administration
>
> Hope you can understand now it well!!